# The team bot did not appear in a team meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business, skype-bots

We are using a Microsoft sample code to join the team meeting and start the recording. The problem which we are facing is When we hit the post method from the postman to join the call using this link in postman (https://testbotaimeet.ngrok.io/joinCall) and body as this:

```
{
"JoinURL": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19:meeting_Y2Y5ODc4ZDUtYmY2Yy00YmVmLTljYTEtYWE4NjcwYjU5ZDc1@thread.v2/0?context=%7B%22Tid%22:%22204d6395-ea6c-4e64-abea-e04cd30845e2%22,%22Oid%22:%225a95f69b-70e2-40d3-8b9a-5810ffcc6ec9%22%7D",
"DisplayName": "Bot"
}
```

We get the output like this:

```
{
    "callId": "5e1f5a00-140c-47fe-9746-7910b6f39ff1",
    "scenarioId": "38b81964-2ae1-476d-a79f-4abf9dd82a95",
    "call": "testbotaimeet.ngrok.io/calls/5e1f5a00-140c-47fe-9746-7910b6f39ff1"
}
```

But the bot did not appear or show in the team meeting why? Please help us with this.

Reference: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/AksSamples/teams-recording-bot

Comment: Have you done all configuration and Prerequisites-https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/AksSamples/teams-recording-bot#prerequisites

Comment: yes. we are getting this output in postman 



{
    "callId": "e51f2c00-0420-44af-a977-88dc307d2346",
    "scenarioId": "bda643f2-4a8e-4dbb-beff-94bef8534279",
    "call": "bot.ngrok.io/calls/e51f2c00-0420-44af-a977-88dc307d2346"
}

Comment: yes..i did. ...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happened with me also, but later I realized that I was passing old meeting URL. Just make sure that you give correct input. When you pass a old meeting url (already used or even cancelled), it still gives you the response. So make sure that inputs are valid and as expected.